# A console full of <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> - Xcode 8 / iOS10

Tags: ios, firebase, analytics, swift3, ios10

I am having issues with Firebase within Xcode 8 / iOS 10 / Swift 3.
Trying to just get Firebase Analytics all set up. However in iOS10, the console gets logged with a plethora of WARNING logs from Firebase. These do not happen when I run iOS 9.3 in the simulator. I took the exact steps as noted here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start

Here is what the log looks like:

```
<FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3402000 started
<FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
<FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to remove checkin auth credentials from Keychain Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-34018 "(null)"
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Error failed to remove all tokens from keychain Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-34018 "(null)"
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> STOP!! Will reset deviceID from memory.
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=6 "(null)"
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> STOP!! Will reset deviceID from memory.
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Error removing keypair status: -34018
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Unable to remove RSA keypair
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Unable to generate keypair.
<FIRAnalytics/WARNING> Failed to get InstanceID: Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=-34018 "(null)"
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=501 "(null)" UserInfo={msg=Missing device credentials. Retry later.}
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to retrieve the default GCM token after 5 retries
```

I also get the following error that pops up about every ~30 seconds (while the errors above all don't repeat):

```
<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> STOP!! Will reset deviceID from memory.
```

Before posting this, I did research and found that the WARNING logs can go away if you enable Keychain Sharing within Capabilities. I am weary of this, however, because no other documentation or explanation was given. And I don't know if that's just masking the errors, or if it's a safe solution here.

Please advise on the safest way to remedy all these WARNING logs.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of  this:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/39560078/6297658. Its just a bug in Swift 3. This is temporary, Firebase should fix it in future updates maybe.

Comment: @Dravidian - Where is it stated that it's a bug? Is it safe to deploy apps with all of these errors?

Comment: You just need to enable *any* entitlement. It's a bug with the iOS 10 Simulator + the Keychain + lack of entitlements.

Comment: If it's just a bug within iOS 10 simulator, and won't affect an actual device, then can I safely disregard the console log errors? (without having to enable any entitlement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update, these errors should no longer appear in the latest version of Firebase when using the Xcode 8.2+ version of the simulator. There was an issue (in fact a couple) with the simulator, and some overly aggressive logging in InstanceID.

Comment: i just got similar warnings, running in Xcode 8.2.1 on an iPad Air 2, (not the simulator), running iOS 10.2

Answer (score 0):

Enable this from firebase

Authentication -> SIGN-IN METHOD -> Email/Password -> Enabled

See The Image Below:

[image]